Ore condition of morphisms whose cone lies in a triangulated subcategory
I'm trying to prove that a certain class of morphisms in a triangulated category form a multiplicative system. More precisely:

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category and $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{T}$ a triangulated subcategory.

Let $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ be the class of morphisms $f$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\text{cone}\,f \in \mathcal{D}$.

I'm trying to prove that $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ satifies the Ore-condition that is


(Ore condition) Let $t: Z\longrightarrow Y$ be in $\Sigma_\mathcal{D}$. Then for each                                $g: M \longrightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{T}$ there is an $s\in \Sigma_\mathcal{D}$ and an $h \in \mathcal{T}$ making the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W @>{h}>> Z\\
@V{s}VV @V{t}VV \\
M @>{g}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
commute. Moreover, the symmetric statement, where $s$ is given and $t$ exists, holds too.
I can find the maps $h$ and $s$ by taking $W = \text{cone}\,(t -g)$ and the corresponding morphisms. But I can't show that $s$ is in $\Sigma_{\mathcal{D}}$. I've looked it up, and found Neemans book on triangulated categories, more precisely, Lemma 1.4.4, but I don't understand how he gets the triangle $Z \longrightarrow Z' \longrightarrow Y'' \longrightarrow Z[1]$.
I posted this question a couple of days ago on StackExchange
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4949094/ore-condition-of-morphisms-whose-cones-lie-in-a-triangulated-subcategory
and have not received an answer yet. So I was hoping someone on here might give some hints.
Thank you!

There's another exposition (for example) in Prop 7.3 of my notes on triangulated categories.

I looked at your notes at Prop. 7.3, but I don't understand how you get that $C_{\Sigma \omega'} \cong \Sigma C_\omega$. What triangle in the composition axiom diagram tells you that?

Using the composition axiom literally tells us that $Y' \to C_w \to \Sigma_Y \to \Sigma_{Y'}$ is a triangle, and hence $C_w \cong \Sigma^{-1} C_{\Sigma w'}$. Right? (It's been a while since I've thought about triangulated categories.)
